# Selenium Loss of Internet Exception Handling using Python and Chromedriver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want my code to be able to handle circumstances when the internet goes down for a period. Currently I'm doing it using a try/except clause with a TimeoutException but that isn't working as Chrome doesn't Timeout when there is no internet, it just returns this page:

> No Internet
>
> Try:
>
> - Checking the network cables, modem and router
> - Reconnecting to Wi-Fi
>
> ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED

Since there's no timeout, my code just continues searching for elements and the loss of internet is not caught.

Is there anyway of raising an exception when there is no internet in chrome?

---

Code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=mypath)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)    
driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)

try:  
    driver.get(url)
    elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).get_attribute("content")

except TimeoutException:
    print('TimeoutException')
```

Comment: @debanjanb, this question has nothing to do with NETERROR error pages, I'm not trying to navigate to any other tabs, please can you explain why you added the duplicate tag?

Comment: Reopened the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you can just detect if element `No Internet` exist

```
def has_connection(driver):
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@jsselect="heading" and @jsvalues=".innerHTML:msg"]')
        return False
    except: return True

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com")

if not has_connection(driver):
    print('No Internet connection, aborted!')
    driver.quit()
    exit()

# connection is good continue
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).get_attribute("content")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I can see that could be a useful workaround - but wouldn't that be dependent on Google Chrome keeping that page format for those instances when there is no internet connection? I'm trying to make the code as robust as possible, so I was hesitant to test for elements on the no internet page.

Comment: it just the easiest way and there are more but selenium itself has no option or function to detect if connection is down.

Answer (score 0):

It´s late but, you can use

```
except exceptionType:
    try:
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//body[@class="neterror"]')
        print('Yes, the internet is down')
    except:
        print('No, the internet is ok')
```